# Changing a ISO date to a Short date JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a function setup to get the following two weeks or months from the selected date from a input date field. However, the problem I'm facing is that I want to get the date to output DD/MM/YYYY but I'm getting the full ISO date where I need the short. Does anyone know how I can go about doing this?

EDIT:

I've added the `moment(date1).format('DD/MM/YYYY');` to test the code but this hasn't provided any results.

```js
function submit() {
  var type = document.getElementById("selectType").value;
  var dateSelected = document.getElementById('datePicker').valueAsDate = new Date();

  if (type === "Months") {
    document.getElementById("pWeeks").className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pMonths").className = "";

    var date1 = dateSelected;
    
    moment(date1).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
    
    var date2 = new Date(date1);
    date2.setMonth(date2.getMonth() + 1);

    document.getElementById("pM1").innerHTML = date1;

    document.getElementById("pM2").innerHTML = date2;

  } else {
    document.getElementById("pWeeks").className = "";
    document.getElementById("pMonths").className = "hidden";

    var date1 = dateSelected;

    var date2 = new Date(date1);
    date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + 7);

    document.getElementById("pW1").innerHTML = date1;

    document.getElementById("pW2").innerHTML = date2;
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="datePicker"><br>
<select id="selectType">
  <option value="Months">Months</option>
  <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
</select><br>
<button id="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<div id="pMonths" class="">
  <p id="pM1"></p>
  <p id="pM2"></p>
</div>
<div id="pWeeks" class="">
  <p id="pW1"></p>
  <p id="pW2"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById("pM1").innerHTML = date1;` you should build first a string with the methods provided by the date object ( getFullYear, getDate, getMonth; see [docu](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp) ). Then you can assign the string to the innerHtml.

If you can use the moment.js then your code which you assign to your innerHtml is `date1 = moment(dateSelected).format('DD/MM/YYYY')`

Also I would recommend Luca's way:

> As for converting the Dates, I would use Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString() passing "en-US"

which would look at your code:

```
dateSelected.toLocaleDateString('en-US')
```

Comment: I've added an update to the main post as I don't know why but it isn't providing any additional output, it's still outputting the date the same.

Comment: It has to be `date1 = moment(dateSelected).format('DD/MM/YYYY');`

Answer (score 2):

First off, you are setting the input value to the current date right here

```
var dateSelected = document.getElementById('datePicker').valueAsDate = new Date();
```

don't do that, it kind of defeats the purpose of having a selector in the first place.

As for converting the Dates, I would use [`Date.prototype.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) passing `"en-US"` as the locale:

```js
console.log((new Date()).toLocaleDateString('en-US')); // format MM/DD/YYY
```

I also fixed how you set the new dates, it now takes one date and adds either one and two months or one and to weeks instead of none and one month and none and one week ;-)

```js
function submit() {
  var type = document.getElementById("selectType").value;
  var dateSelected = document.getElementById('datePicker').valueAsDate;

  if (type === "Months") {
    document.getElementById("pWeeks").className = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("pMonths").className = "";

    var date1 = dateSelected;

    var datePlusOne = new Date(date1);
    datePlusOne.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 1);
    
    var datePlusTwo = new Date(date1);
    datePlusTwo.setMonth(date1.getMonth() + 2);

    document.getElementById("pM1").innerHTML = datePlusOne.toLocaleDateString('en-US');

    document.getElementById("pM2").innerHTML = datePlusTwo.toLocaleDateString('en-US');

  } else {
    document.getElementById("pWeeks").className = "";
    document.getElementById("pMonths").className = "hidden";

    var date1 = dateSelected;

    var datePlusOne = new Date(date1);
    datePlusOne.setDate(date1.getDate() + 7);
    
    var datePlusTwo = new Date(date1);
    datePlusTwo.setDate(date1.getDate() + 14);

    document.getElementById("pW1").innerHTML = datePlusOne.toLocaleDateString('en-US');

    document.getElementById("pW2").innerHTML = datePlusTwo.toLocaleDateString('en-US');
  }
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="datePicker"><br>
<select id="selectType">
  <option value="Months">Months</option>
  <option value="Weeks">Weeks</option>
</select><br>
<button id="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
<div id="pMonths" class="">
  <p id="pM1"></p>
  <p id="pM2"></p>
</div>
<div id="pWeeks" class="">
  <p id="pW1"></p>
  <p id="pW2"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use MomentJS library to keep things simple:

Include the library :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
document.getElementById("pM1").innerHTML = moment(date1).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
document.getElementById("pM2").innerHTML = moment(date2).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

and in the else:

```
document.getElementById("pW1").innerHTML = moment(date1).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
document.getElementById("pW2").innerHTML = moment(date2).add(1, 'week').format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

Comment: Can you add a working example, as when I used this in my code I didn't get any changes.